# Find the most liked product from people who like a specific product in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d573/7)

I would like to know how to find out the most liked product from users who liked the product `H135` with the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE likes
    (`user_id` int,`product_id`int)
;

INSERT INTO likes
    (`user_id`,`product_id`)
VALUES
    (1,22),
    (1,44),
    (2,33),
    (2,44),
    (3,22),
    (3,55),
    (4,44),
    (4,11),
    (5,22),
    (5,44),
    (5,33) 

;
CREATE TABLE products
    (`product_id` int,`product_name`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO products
    (`product_id`,`product_name`)
VALUES
    (11,'N570'),
    (22,'KA89'),
    (33,'A321'),
    (44,'H135'),
    (55,'C839')
;
```

The expected output should be like this

```
Liked_product  users_who_like_it_also_like     Result   
H135           KA89                            3
```

I have tried `self join` but it doesn't yield any result:

```
SELECT p.product_name,p2.product_name AS other_liked_products,
COUNT(l2.product_id) AS users_who_like_it_also_like 
FROM likes l 
INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = l.product_id
INNER JOIN likes l2 ON l.product_id = l2.product_id
INNER JOIN products p2 ON p2.product_id = l2.product_id
WHERE l.product_id = 44 
AND l2.product_id <> 44
GROUP BY l.product_id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You probably just need an `order by` statement after the `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about ties you can use:

```
select 'H135' as liked_product,
       p.product_name as users_who_like_it_also_like,
       count(*) as result
  from likes l
  join products p
    on p.product_id = l.product_id
 where exists (select 1
          from likes x
         where x.user_id = l.user_id
           and x.product_id = 44)
   and l.product_id <> 44
 group by p.product_name
 order by 3 desc
 limit 1
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d573/17/0

In your sample data KA89 actually has a count of 2 and is tied with A321.

This will show both in an aggregated list on one row as being tied with a count of 2:

```
select liked_product,
       group_concat(users_who_like_it_also_like) as users_who_like_it_also_like,
       result
  from (select 'H135' as liked_product,
               p.product_name as users_who_like_it_also_like,
               count(*) as result
          from likes l
          join products p
            on p.product_id = l.product_id
         where exists (select 1
                  from likes x
                 where x.user_id = l.user_id
                   and x.product_id = 44)
           and l.product_id <> 44
         group by p.product_name) x
 group by liked_product, result
 order by result desc limit 1
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d573/19/0